# XMLHttpRequest working fine in content script but not in background script - Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm switching requests from content script to background script and the code is identical but somehow the XMLHttpRequest doesn't keep me logged in.

My goal is to log in a user and change his password - which requires 2 POST requests. The second one fails.

Background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    
    // FIRST REQUEST
    var loginRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    loginRequest.open("POST", "https://.../login.php", true);
    loginRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    loginRequest.send("user credentials...");

    loginRequest.onload = function() {

      // SECOND REQUEST
      var changeRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      changeRequest.open("POST", "https://.../changePassword", true);
      changeRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      changeRequest.send("old pass... new pass...");
      changeRequest.onload = function() {

        // ISSUE: changeRequest.responseURL is back at the login page? WHY?
        if (changeRequest.responseText.includes("Password successfully changed!")) {
          sendResponse({passwordChanged: true});
        } else {
          sendResponse({passwordChanged: false});
        }
      }
    }

    return true;

});
```

PLEASE NOTE: This code works perfectly fine in the content script!

Comment: The content script reuses cookies from the web page (I guess these are session cookies) so when performing the request in the background script you need to set the same cookies on an outgoing request, probably by reading doocument.cookie in the content script, sending the relevant cookies to the background script, then set them via chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders with 'extraHeaders' parameter, look for examples.

Comment: It's also possible the site is checking `Referer` header so you'll have to set it manually using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders with 'extraHeaders' parameter.

Comment: Did everything you said, still not working...I compared request and response headers in both content script and background script and they are the same.

Comment: The `Referer` header as well? Try also inspecting in a separate tool like Fiddler or mitmproxy.

Comment: This may sound crazy, but I succeeded when I deleted all the cookies... I then realized this could be done with ONLY 1 EXTRA LINE without whole webRequest API, using `loginRequest.anonymous = true;` which does not even appear in documentation.

Comment: I also installed Fiddler, thanks for recommending it, amazing tool!

Answer (score 0):

```
loginRequest.anonymous = true;
```

has solved the problem due to unnecessary cookies when sending from background script.